# How can I configure a QueueChannel with Poller using Java DSL?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

we used to configure the poller in int:chain like below, the inboundChannel is configured with queue

```
    <int:chain id="messageProcessChain" input-channel="inboundChannel" >
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
```

This time, we'd like to programmatically initialize int flows, so using DSL. my test code as below:

```
                            Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(inConnFactory).destination(flowProperties.getInputQueue()))
                            .channel(MessageChannels.queue(mongoDbChannelMessageStore,"groupId"))
//                            .enrichHeaders(testHeaders)
                            .handle(m -> {
                                System.out.println("test handler");

                                logger.info("test dsl flow:"+m.getPayload().toString());
                                },c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(flowProperties.getInboudFixedRate()).maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
                            .get()
```

it cannot work with the *".enrichHeaders(testHeaders)"*, due to'No poller has been defined for endpoint', but neither can I configure a poller for the header richer because it has an implicit SubscribableChannel?

In such case, can only use a bridge to connect the two channel? Is there some other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.enrichHeaders(headers, e -> e.poller(...))`.

However, you should NOT use a queue channel with a message-driven channel adapter, you will likely lose messages in the event of a failure.

To achieve concurrency, increase concurrency on the adapter.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure 'the event of a failure' you mentioned, did you mean  'Because of the failures that can occur at any point within your message flow, EIP components that buffer messages also introduce a point where messages could be lost.' ?

Comment: Exactly, the message driven adapter will push as many messages it has into the queue (unless you set a queue size). Those messages will be acknowledged on the broker and are now sitting in memory. If the server crashes (or loses power), those messages will be lost. They will not be queued in memory if you use the default `DirectChannel`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, well understood, won't use memory queue, ha~